# Airplay and wifi

Tags: ios, airplay

I am having trouble with Airplaying to a raspberry Pi device using the shairplay software.

The raspberry pi device is on 2.4 Ghz wifi. Iwconfig lists the wifi quality as:

Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=77/100  Noise level=0/100

When I airplay music to it from my iMac (connected to router via ethernet), airplay works perfectly. No dropouts or hiccups.

When I try to airplay music to it from my iPhone, I get many dropouts. When I connect to the 5Ghz wifi band with my iPhone, airplay works well, but still some dropouts in music and sometimes disconnections. When I connect to the 2.4 gz wifi band with my iPhone, airplay is almost unusable, many dropouts and disconnects after a few minutes.

How can I troubleshoot an Airplay problem (sending to a wifi device from an iPhone on the same wifi network)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like interference on 2.4 gHz would make the most sense. Second would be high beaconing rates. Without a wireless scan analysis it will be hard to pin this down. Even on 5 Ghz AirPlay can drop and be laggy, so I would try Bluetooth audio or wired output if you need something rock solid.

You've ruled out the pic being able to handle the workload with the wired test from the Mac. Why not use the remote app on the phone to play music from the Mac to the pi?

Comment: well, not everything can be controlled from the remote app (e.g., soundcloud, other music apps on iPhone) and I'm pessimistic about remote app continuing to work in the future.

What kind of information would I need to gather to perform a wireless scan analysis? Is there an app or command line utility you recommend?

Comment: I like WiFi Explorer if your budget is less than $150 - you'll want hardware and software if you can spend $300 to $650 for the stuff that's quite good.